# How to fix a specific Declaration of case-insensitive constants is deprecated warning

Tags: php, constants, case-insensitive, deprecation-warning

I have a Wordpress plugin that is no longer maintained but I have not found any plugin that satisfactorily replaces it. As a result, updates to PHP are starting to generate warnings in the plugin. I have little PHP knowledge and am not sure what, exactly, I need to do to update the following snippet so as to avoid the warning "Declaration of case-insensitive constants is deprecated" under PHP 7.3.

Here is the snippet:

```
$uploads = wp_upload_dir();

define( 'DOIFD_SERVICE', '', true );
define( 'DOIFD_VERSION', '2.1.6' );
define( 'DOIFD_URL', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) );
define( 'DOIFD_DIR', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
define( 'DOIFD_DOWNLOAD_DIR', $uploads[ 'basedir' ] . '/doifd_downloads/' );
define( 'DOIFD_DOWNLOAD_URL', $uploads[ 'baseurl' ] . '/doifd_downloads/' );
define( 'DOIFD_IMG_URL', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'public/assets/img/' );
define( 'DOIFD_ADMIN_IMG_URL', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'admin/assets/img/' );
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/define mentions "Defining case-insensitive constants is deprecated as of PHP 7.3.0.", so remove third parameter of your first `define` call (and make sure it's always used with uppercase letters).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 10):

The `case_insensitive` parameter is [no longer supported](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php), so you should remove the third argument (`true`) from the function call.

In your case, the important part is that you need to check the code to see if `DOIFD_SERVICE` is used in places where it's not all caps, for example `doifd_service`, and replace all the instances with all caps `DOIFD_SERVICE` (there are probably some in the code, or else the parameter would probably not have been set to `true`)

In other words, replace this:

```
define( 'DOIFD_SERVICE', '', true );
```

With this:

```
define( 'DOIFD_SERVICE', '' );
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to change

```
define( 'DOIFD_SERVICE', '', true );
                           ^^^^^^^
```

to

```
define( 'DOIFD_SERVICE', '');
```

An issue can be, that `doifd_service` and `doIFd_Service` and ... are not longer defined. If this is important, add

```
 define( 'doifd_service', '');
```

Mixed cases (CamelCase) are not usual in combination with underscore.

Answer (score 0):

code is different i use "SaFly-Curl-Patch" third party plugin for solving php error there is same error so to fix it, goto plugin folder find edit safly plugin,

```
define('SCP_INC', 'safly', TRUE);
```

To

```
define('SCP_INC', 'safly');
```

probably on line no 26, hope this work for you!